# How to change pnrp.net peer name resolver to custom domain peer name resolver using WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, p2p, wcf-binding, pnrp

I want to create peer to peer software with WCF as peer name resolver service. When I create a peer name and register it, I've URL like `[anewpeername].pnrp.net`.

```cs
var peerName = new PeerName("anewpeername", PeerNameType.Unsecured);
var pnReg = new PeerNameRegisteration();
pnReg.PeerName = peerName;
pnReg.Port = 5474;
pnReg.Start();
```

Now, peer URL is `anewpeername.pnrp.net`.

I need change default peer name resolver domain||server `pnrp.net` to my own domain||server.

My question is about **how to change a pnrp.net peer name resolver domain to custom peer name resolver domain?**

Example:

`anewpeername.pnrp.net` change to `anewpeername.example.com`.

Thank you.

Comment: Can everyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many months, I found another solution for peer to peer system and not need pnrp solution.